# Regular Expression from long string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following characters running on DataFrame:

```
1.83\n1\n71%\n4.25\nX\n18%\n4.30\n2\n11%\n+88
```

I'm trying regular expression to achieve this: `1.83\n4.25\n4.30`

I've so far tried this code snippet in pandas:

```
import re

clean_dict = {'[nX%+]':'','\n1':''}
```

but this fails to remove the other unwanted characters.

I'm using regex101.com for testing

What's the best way to resolve this?

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're leveraging the Python regex library anywhere. Were you trying by some other means?

Comment: @dfundako Sorry I forgot to say that I'm running the regex in Pandas Dataframe if that helps. Still new in asking questions; hopefully I'll get better :)

Comment: `1.83\n1\n71%\n4.25\nX\n18%\n4.30\n2\n11%\n+88` is not a string without quotes around it. I mention this because the *type* of quotes are important. Is it, for example, a *raw string* as one of the individuals who provided an answer assumed?

Comment: @Booboo I get you thanks. It's a raw string

Comment: Please try `df['A'].str.replace(r'(?m)^(?!\d+\.\d+$).*\n*', '').str.strip()`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The solution works perfect. Thank you. Let me understand how it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['A'].str.replace(r'(?m)^(?!\d+\.\d+$).*\n*', '').str.strip()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a2WBs8/1). Details:

- `(?m)` - `re.M` inline option, makes `^` match start of a line position and `$` match the end of a line position
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?!\d+\.\d+$)` - no one or more digits, `.` and one or more digits till the end of the line
- `.*` - the whole line, zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\n*` - zero or more line feed chars.

The `.str.strip()` is necessary to remove the trailing newline char if there was a match at the end of the string.

Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1.83\n1\n71%\n4.25\nX\n18%\n4.30\n2\n11%\n+88']})
>>> df['A'].str.replace(r'(?m)^(?!\d+\.\d+$).*\n*', '').str.strip()
0    1.83\n4.25\n4.30
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Wiltor Stribizew This solution works on the fly. Thank you for explaining :)

Comment: @Wiltor Stribizew Sure. I've accepted the answer. Let me know if not as I'm still learning the platform

Comment: @Wilktor Stribizew Done and thank for your patience as well.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the string you want:

Not sure if it will meet all your needs though. Your question is lacking some details.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(['1.83\n1\n71%\n4.25\nX\n18%\n4.30\n2\n11%\n+88'], columns=['A'])

def match(x):
    matches = re.findall(r'(---\d\.\d+|\d\.\d+)', x.replace('\n', '---'))
    new_string = ''.join([x for x in matches])
    return new_string.replace('---', '\\n')


df['new_string'] = df["A"].apply(lambda x: match(x))
print(df)

#                                                A        new_string
# 0  1.83\n1\n71%\n4.25\nX\n18%\n4.30\n2\n11%\n+88  1.83\n4.25\n4.30
```

Comment: Note that I'm tying the code in Pandas DataFrame and want to clean the string to leave exactly this: 1.83\n4.25\n4.30

Comment: @Booboo It's a learning curve. The string as per the dataframe has no quotes. Hence my solution code extract in my question works but not quite 100%. Hopefully this provides some clarity. Let me know if not

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered not using regex?

```
text = '1.83\n1\n71%\n4.25\nX\n18%\n4.30\n2\n11%\n+88'
split = text.split('\n')
print('\n'.join([split[0], split[3], split[6]])
```

You may need to replace `'\n'.join(...)` with `'\\n'.join(...)` if you want to retain `\n` as two readable characters in the resulting string instead of them being one line break character.

Explanation:

First you `split` the entire text into segments separated by `\n`, where `\n` is then discarded. This gives you a list of segments.

You can access each segment by using the index via `text[index]`, in this case `split[0]` to get the first segment in the list named `split`.

You then create a list with the segments you desire to use `[split[0], split[3], split[6]]`. The remaining segments are being unused.

You re-join the segments in this new list by using `''.join(list_of_segments)`, where you specify that you want to join them with the `\n` characters. Since `\` is an escape character, you need to escape it as well, therefore you use `\\n`, which results in `'\\n'.join(list_of_segments)`.

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks

Comment: Then check the edit I made. Use `\\n` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Great thanks. The solution works, just need to understand the how.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: Most appreciated. Many thanks for helping out.